# Como funciona o evento onchange no upload de um arquivo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando implementar um player de musica utilizando javascript, que funciona com o upload de um arquivo de áudio(.mp3), no script quando ocorre o upload do arquivo, que ocorre com o evento 'onload' a função criada tem a variável 'files' e depois tocar o arquivo. Como o arquivo é tocado se não aparentemente referencia a variável que recebe o arquivo 'file'?

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" /> 
    <audio id="audio" controls="controls"></audio> 
</div>
```

Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {

    var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio");


    file.onchange = function() {
        var files = this.files;
        audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    }

};
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifiquei o `id` do seu elemento de áudio e do file pra não confundir sua variável com o elemento em si.

```
<div id="content">
  <input type="file" id="arquivo" accept="audio/*" /> 
  <audio id="musica" controls="controls"></audio> 
</div>

var musica = document.getElementById("musica"); 
var arquivo = document.getElementById("arquivo");
```

Você armazena na variável `musica` o elemento de áudio([object HTMLAudioElement]) do seu documento, e na `arquivo` e elemento `file`, e não o arquivo importado.

O que acontece é que toda vez que acontece uma mudança no `file`, você armazena uma lista de arquivos na `var files` usando o `.files`, e você passa o primeiro elemento `files[0]` para a `src` do elemento áudio, nesse trecho.

```
var files = this.files;
musica.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
```

Quando você da o `play` na variável `musica`, você está dizendo para reproduzir o elemento `audio`, que contém a nova `src` do `file` importado.

Mais informações sobre essa mudança do `src`: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURl

Mais informações sobre o input `file`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Você pode observar a mudança do `src` do elemento áudio inspecionado a página(crtl + shif + i no Chrome) e importando um novo arquivo.

Espero que ajude!

Comment: obrigado pela explicação, ajudou mto, mas minha duvida persiste na parte do papel desempenhado pela variável  `files`.

Comment: Editei a resposta com a explicação do `files`